Нормально ли во Vue использовать watch для запросов к api?
В своем компоненте я использую watch для отслеживания изменений номера страницы, чтобы подгружать контент в соответствии с номером страницы, номер при клике попадает в query запрос и оттуда отслеживается watch. Нормальная ли это практика?
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { PAGE_BLOG, QUERY_PARAMS } from "../constants.js";
import { useArticlesStore } from "../stores/articlesStore";
import { getQueryParameter } from "../utils/routerUtils.js";

const articlesStore = useArticlesStore();
const router = useRouter();
let page = ref(1);

articlesStore.getLastItem();

watch(
  () => parseInt(getQueryParameter(router, QUERY_PARAMS.PAGE)) || 1,
  async (currentPage) => {
    page.value = currentPage;
    await articlesStore.getDataByParams({
      page: page.value,
      limit: 6,
    });
  },
  { immediate: true, deep: true }
);

</script>


а почему ты думаешь, что это может быть не нормальная практика?

Смотрела какое-то открытое собеседование по vue, там интервьюер сказал, что использование watch, watchEffect - бэд прэктис, но я нигде такой информации не нашла

А зачем watch? - если можно вызывать функцию по клику на "кнопке" страницы. И если у вас МНОГО-пользовательский сайт - вы каждую страницу с сервера "зовете"? Может разделить контент на разделы и загружать конкретный и далее уже листать "быстро" и без нагрузки на сервер? Вам решать конечно )))

если использовать watch так как он задумывался - это не будет плохой практикой. А что конкретно отслеживает этот watch?

Этот watch отслеживает страницу в query запросе https://site/blog?page=2, при смене номера получает порцию данных с сервера

Михаил, а как это реализовать? Добавить на сайт разделы и уже к разделам добавлять пагинацию, а не ко всему контенту? А если у меня на главной будет бесконечная лента и там должны отображаться все категории? И если вызывать функцию при клике на кнопку, как нам тогда возвращать этот же список статей при переходе по ссылке, а не при клике на кнопку?

vue-router же у вас есть, можете использовать вложенные маршруты и пушить туда номер страницы https://v3.router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Павел, спасибо! Можно переделать с использованием вложенных параметров. Только непонятно чем вызов функции при нажатии на кнопку лучше вотчера, если вотчер вызывается с той же переодичностью (при смене страницы)?

@yaxz насчет лучше или хуже не могу сказать. Интереса ради - если в адресной строке сразу вбить адрес с номером страницы - watch отработает?

Павел, да, отрабатывает и при переходах и если просто на странице в адресной строке менять тоже отрабатывает

Мне кажется, что в данном случае использовать watch - это плохая практика, поскольку нарушается логика работы со страницами. Нужно сначала по клику запрашивать нужную страницу, а по ответу выставлять номер страницы (ведь возможен случай, что ответ не пришёл или в ответе какие-то ошибки). А здесь получается, что мы сначала выставляем номер страницы, а потом эту страницу запрашиваем. А что если такой страницы нет?

@ВикторКарев , Если такой страницы нет (ответ пуст) появляется страница not found, а если пришла ошибка, то выводится сообщение с указанием ошибки, контент не отрисовывается в этих двух случаях, если указать в адресе неверный номер страницы или просто написать какие-нибудь буквы, будет not found
